# How to convert day of year (0-365) into actual date and set the values as x axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvasjs

I have a text file which contains day of year as a column and a value associated to it.

something like this

```
day value
59   0.2
60   0.6
63  5.07
```

Here the day column represents the day in a year i.e, 59/365, 60/365, 63/365.

```
dataPoints.push({x: parseFloat(x1), y: parseFloat(y1)});// x1 and y1 are variables containing "59" and "0.2" .
```

I was able to get this data and push them as x and y coordinates and display a line chart using CanvasJS.

But I am trying to display the actual date on the x axis so that the values correspond to a particular date
 i.e, Feb 28 , March 1 ,March 6.

How can i convert the day into actual date and then pass it into the dataPoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the milliseconds and use the function `toLocaleString` to get the month and day.

**Important:** Be careful with leap-years.

```js
var day = 59;
var date = new Date(day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // This will place that date in YEAR 1970.

var options = { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(date.toLocaleString('us', options))
```

## Docs

- [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the date from day of year as follows :

```
var dayOfYear = 63;
var initialDate = new Date(2018, 0); // initialized at first day of 2018
var date = new Date(initialDate.setDate(dayOfYear)); // add your dayOfYear
```